# How many ways are there for three persons to register in five classes?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the number of ways that $3$ people register in $5$ classes. Each of them can register for as many classes as they want but they must register in at least one class.

I thought that for each class, a person has two choices. The person can register or not. So there are $2^5-1$ ways for a person to  register in the classes. (as each person must register for at least in one class). So given $3$ persons, total number of ways would be $(2^5-1)^3$. Is it correct?

But on the other hand, I thought that for each class, each person can register or not so for each class there are $2^3-1$ ways to be registered. So the final number would be $(2^3-1)^5$, Which one is correct?

Comment: Please clarify the rules.  You say "each of them can register in as many classes as he wants" but then tell us that the number must be $>0$. Are there any other restrictions?

Comment: Your title and your body are not alike.  Assuming classes don't overlap and each must register in at least one, and other standard assumptions... then yes, each *individual* person would have $2^5-1$ options for registering or not for five different classes... but your question is about *three* people, not just one, so there is still more to be done for a final answer.

Comment: @lulu No there aren't any restrictions. I meant they shouldn't register in just one class. They can register for more but they must at least register in one of them

Comment: And the header says $3$ classes, but you meant $5$?  If so...and assuming there really are no other rules, then I agree with the answer $(2^5-1)^3$.

Comment: @lulu You're right. I'm so sorry. I edited my question. Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: I don't understand your second approach.  If nothing else, there was never a rule preventing none of the three from registering for a given class.  Should add:  I think you will find it difficult to repair the second approach, as it isn't easy to incorporate the rule that each student much register in at least one class.  Should be possible, however, if you want the exercise.

Comment: Just to confirm that the problem really is the "no empty set" rule, note that if you allow a student to register for $0$ classes, then we do indeed have $(2^5)^3=(2^3)^5$.

Comment: @lulu So with the "no empty set" rule, which one is correct?

Comment: Please note the question says that each person must register for at least one class. It does not say that each class must have one of three persons registered. In other words, it is possible that all of them register only for first two classes and none of them register for the third. With that, your first approach is correct.

Comment: @MathLover You're right. I get it now. Thanks. And thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

$(2^5-1)^3$ is the correct answer, but leads interestingly to your next point.

If you do the calculation via the number of students that enrol for each class, you should use $2^3$ for each class, as no student may enrol for a particular class.

However, every student is required to enrol on at least one class, so we need to subtract from $(2^5)^3$ all the cases where one student has failed to enrol.

But this double counts scenarios where two student fails to enrol, so we need to count them back in.

Finally, we have now failed to count the scenario where all students fail to enrol, so we remove this.

There are $3\cdot2^{10}$ of the first type, $3\cdot2^5$ of the second, and $1$ of the third.

So we have $2^{15}-3\cdot2^{10}+3\cdot2^5-1$ from your second attempt, but this equals the $(2^5-1)^3$ from your first attempt!